# Plotting svg circles based off csv data

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to plot circles from data in my csv file, but the circles are not appearing on the svg canvas. I believe the problem stems from how I load in the data (it gets loaded as an array of objects), but I'm not quite sure how to figure out what to do next.

Based off this tutorial: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element

D3.js code:

```
        var circleData = d3.csv("files/data.csv", function (error, data) {
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d['KCComment'] = +d['KCComment'];
                d['pscoreResult'] = +d['pscoreResult'];
                d['r'] = +d['r'];
            });
            console.log(data);
        });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 480)
            .attr("height", 480);

        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(circleData)
            .enter()
            .append("circle");

        var circleAttributes = circles
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.KCComment; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.pscoreResult; })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
            .style("fill", "green");

        var text = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(circleData)
            .enter()
            .append("text");

        var textLabels = text
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.KCComment; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.pscoreResult; })
            .text(function (d) { return "( " + d.KCComment + ", " + d.pscoreResult + " )"; })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
            .attr("fill", "red");
```

What the CSV looks like:

```
fmname, fmtype, KCComment, pscoreResult, r
test1, type1, 7.1, 8, 39
test2, type2, 1.2, 3, 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the circle-drawing code within the `d3.csv` function's callback, so it's only processed when the data is available.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, circleData) {
  circleData.forEach(function (d) {
    d['KCComment'] = +d['KCComment'];
    d['pscoreResult'] = +d['pscoreResult'];
    d['r'] = +d['r'];
  });
  console.log(circleData);
  // Do the SVG drawing stuff
  ...
  // Finished
});
```

Also note that instead of setting `var circleData = d3.csv(`... you should just define it in the callback function.

Here's a plunker with the working code: http://embed.plnkr.co/fzBX0o/preview

You'll be able to see a number of further issues now: both circles are overlapping and only one quarter is visible. That's because your `KCComment` and `pscoreResult` values used to define the circles' `cx` and `cy` are too small. Try multiplying them up so that the circles move right and down and are a bit more visible! Same is true of the text locations, but I'll leave those problems for you to solve

Comment: This helps! I'm also new to using JavaScript, so was unaware of how the callbacks worked.